# get ServerStatus using Scala/Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to add a REST endpoint to my application where users can query for `getStatus`. The only purpose of this endpoint would be check if the server is active and ready to accept requests.

But rather than displaying a static text or date, I was hoping to return *how long* the server (play server) has been active since.

Is this possible? I would like to do it the most Scala/Play way possible.

Comment: you can initialize a timestamp at the moment when your application starts, and then give a difference from it (nothing Scala-specific here, except that the timestamp variable will be immutable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be as simple as the following controller:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

class UptimeController extends Controller {

  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

  def uptime = Action {
    val uptimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
    Ok(s"$uptimeInMillis ms")
  }
}
```

And then declare the following route:

```
GET     /uptime          controllers.UptimeController.uptime
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka.system(implicit app: Application)`'s method `uptime` to get the number of seconds the Play app has been alive.